# Column defined in source Dataset could not be found in the actual source

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF Copy Data flow and I'm getting the following error at runtime:

[image]

My source is defined as follows:

[image]

In my data set, the column is defined as shown below:

[image]

As you can see from the second image, the column IsLiftStation is defined in the source. Any idea why ADF cannot find the column?

Comment: This isn't an answer, per se, but an observation that I've had this happen to me once when I did all of the things you did. I got that error until I left it alone for several hours. I pulled my hair out one night trying all the things, and came back 8 hours later and it worked. If you don't get a better answer, you might try that. "Leave it alone for a while" is a bad answer, but as best I recall, I literally walked away from it, came back the next day, and triggered it because I wanted to see the error again with fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same error.  You can solve this by either selecting all columns (*) in the source and then mapping those you want to the sink schema, or by 'clearing' the mapping in which case the ADF Copy component will auto map to columns in the sink schema (best if columns have the same names in source and sink).  Either of these approaches works.

Unfortunately,  clicking the import schema button in the mapping tab doesn't work.  It does produce the correct column mappings based on the columns in the source query but I still get the original error 'the column could not be located in the actual source' after doing this mapping.

Answer (score 1):

could you check that is there a column named 'ae_type_id' in your schema? If that's the case, could you remove that column and try again? The columns in the schema must be aligned with columns in the query.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this. All columns in the schema must be included in the query, in the same order, for the pipeline to work. Thanks for this.

Comment: Actually, after specifying the query, you could click the import schema button at mapping tab again. Then the UI will automatically import the schema based on the query and overwrite your schema in dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by an incomplete schema in one of the data sources.  My solution is:

1. Step through the data flow selecting the first schema, Import projection
2. Go to the flow and Data Preview
3. Repeat for each step.

In my case, there were trailing commas in one of the CSV files.  This caused automated column names to be created in the import allowing me to fix the data file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me and none of the other solutions above worked. What finally worked for me was a simple workaround they may or may not work for you: I changed the source data setting "First row as header" to False, then went back to Mapping in the pipeline and mapped the column indexes to the target fields.

This of course requires that I now deal with the actual header row ending up in my target data table. Not ideal but this did enable me to progress past this error.